# Express SSL redirect not working for root /

Tags: node.js, ssl, express

I use a wildcard match at the end of my Express route declarations to test if the connection is not HTTPS and if not, to redirect to the HTTPS version of the URI.

This works for everything except root, i.e., www.domain.com. This is a bit of a problem because domain.com serves a SPA.

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
        if (req.headers['X-forwarded-proto'] != 'https') {
            res.redirect('https://domain.com/#' + url_path);
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/#' + url_path);
        }
});
```

I noticed that this chunk of code does not even get called when the URL is the root domain. I think this might be because I also declare:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, 'public')));`

This is necessary for the SPA to serve all of the assets. When I remove this line, my route handler is now called for the root domain, but my home page now infinitely redirects.

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy such as Nginx? Could you also please include your web server configuration so we can check how the request headers are set.

Comment: I use AWS Load Balancer which doesn't really have much configuration. I can confirm that X-forwarded-proto is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a custom route to server my SPA file, rename index.html so that Express would not try to serve it instead of my route.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who might still be struggeling with this, I had the same problem deploying my React-Express App on Heroku. I used a middleware: "heroku-ssl-redirect". The solution for me was to put this middleware up in the hierarchy (now its the first middleware I am applying):

```
var sslRedirect = require("heroku-ssl-redirect");
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const e = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(sslRedirect());

// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('*', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('App is listening on port ' + port);
```